# How to do POST using requests module with Flask server?

Tags: python, post, flask, python-requests

I am having trouble uploading a file to my Flask server using the Requests module for Python.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/Upload/'


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return """
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    <p>%s</p>
    """ % "<br>".join(os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I am able to upload a file via web page, but I wanted to upload file with the requests module like this:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000', files={'random.txt': open('random.txt', 'rb')})
```

It keeps returning 400 and saying that "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand"

I feel like I am missing something simple, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have `<input>` with `name=file` so you need

```
 files={'file': ('random.txt', open('random.txt', 'rb'))}
```

Examples in requests doc: [POST a Multipart-Encoded File](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/?highlight=post-a-multipart-encoded-file#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

Answer (score 5):

You upload the file as the `random.txt` field:

```
files={'random.txt': open('random.txt', 'rb')}
#      ^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is the field name
```

but look for a field named `file` instead:

```
file = request.files['file']
#                    ^^^^^^ the field name
```

Make those two match; using `file` for the `files` dictionary, for example:

```
files={'file': open('random.txt', 'rb')}
```

Note that `requests` will automatically detect the filename for that open fileobject and include it in the part headers.